# Ubuntu 16.04 - Right channel audio playing on both sides of headset. No left channel

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, sound, pulseaudio, soundcard

In Sound Settings, when I test sound for my Line Out, my Front Right plays on both sides of my headset. Playing the Front Left I can hear *incredibly* faintly.

I have pavucontrol, and it doesn't seem to give me any more information on the problem. I noticed my "Built-In Audio" was set to Analog Stereo Duplex.

I haven't really installed audio drivers, but any drivers I try are out of date and/or will not compile.

I've looked at alsamixer, and as far as I can tell, all my LR channels are equal.

Edit:

Okay! I have discovered more details! Firstly, I forgot to mention I'm dual-booting with Windows. I've found that when switching to Windows, the problem persists. But after some time or some event, it fixed itself! I'm currently looking for possible causes (trying to retrace my steps), but I'm still not positive on the cause.

Something to note, sometimes on Windows, my headset plays mono-audio (both speakers play something like an average of both channels), instead of the weird audio problem described in the title.

Hazarding a guess, I'd say that Ubuntu is messing with the sound card settings (not sure if this is possible), and because of this, the problem persists to Windows, but something on Windows causes a reset of the sound card, fixing it. I don't know where I'd start to fix this though.

Comment: I've had this exact same issue before, I remember messing around with hdajackretask and getting it to work again but I can't remember the exact details and I've had this happen again